# grunt serve and CORS

Tags: python, angularjs, gruntjs, cors

My team uses grunt serve to do live recompiling and reload of our webapp so we can edit and see changes in near-real time.  Our application uses AngluarJS, so all action on the site takes place via API calls to the server.

The grunt server runs on `localhost:9000`, but the server that manages the actual data is written in Python and runs at `localhost:8000`.  Because of this, we end up having CORS difficulties hitting the API at a "different domain."  The solution right now is to open up a new instance of Chrome with the `--disable-web-security` flag set, but for a variety of reasons we need to move away from that.

**Is there a way that we can get both grunt serve and the Python serve serving from the same domain, or any other way to eliminate this CORS issue?**

Comment: I believe you can set up proxies. see https://github.com/saschakiefer/generator-openui5/wiki/How-to-setup-a-proxy-to-avoid-CORS-issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are tutorials on this already, hope this helps, you can use proxies:
https://github.com/drewzboto/grunt-connect-proxy

Tutorial:
https://github.com/saschakiefer/generator-openui5/wiki/How-to-setup-a-proxy-to-avoid-CORS-issues

taken from page:

```
connect: {
    options: {
        port: 8080,
        livereload: 35729,
        hostname: "localhost",
        base: "."
    },
    proxies: {
        context: "/Northwind",  // When the url contains this...
        host: "services.odata.org", // Proxy to this host
        changeOrigin: true
    },
    livereload: {
        options: {
            middleware: function(connect, options) {
                if (!Array.isArray(options.base)) {
                    options.base = [options.base];
                }

                // Setup the proxy
                var middlewares = [require("grunt-connect-proxy/lib/utils").proxyRequest];

                // Serve static files.
                options.base.forEach(function(base) {
                    middlewares.push(connect.static(base));
                });

                return middlewares;
            }
        }
    }
}
```